# Can MutationObserver manipulate the same target element and not fire in a loop?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I added a mutation observer on a table element for `childList` and `subtree`. I did not add `attributes` config on the observer. Based on the number of columns and available screen width it would hide/show columns by removing/adding a CSS class. Now this table can also be modified by the angular framework which would cause DOM Node modifications on the table. It seems like mutation observer is getting fired in a loop even for the CSS class changes made by the observer. Is this an expected behavior of MutationObserver?

Comment: Can you add some code so we have a [MCVE] to look at and debug?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behavior. Simply check some condition to avoid mutating the DOM. Like a flag variable or an attribute/class on the affected element.

Comment: Thank you! I do not want the observer to be fired at all for class name changes. Since I just added `childList` and `subtree` I expected it not to fire on class name changes.

Comment: Since the observer is invoked it can only mean some DOM mutation is triggering it. If it's not your code then it's something else so you may need to find a condition tailored for your use case which we can't guess without seeing a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve).